# How to calculate the correlation between categorical ordered and categorical binary variables

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

How I would calculate the correlation between 9 categorical binary variablçes (0,1) and 12 categorical ordered variables (1-3, 1-5) using R?

Comment: Out of concern that this could be arbitrary and meaningless, I wouldn't do it.  I would stop and ask myself why I am even proposing such a procedure; I would consider what my actual underlying objective is; and I would inquire whether there might be a different procedure that would achieve my aims.

Comment: I'd suggest using some kind of graphical tool, like a heatmap to understand the relation between categorical variables (a simple table could be enough with a small number of categories).

Comment: For each pair of binary and ordered variables, you could use Cochran-Armitage test for the test of association and either Freeman's theta or epsilon squared for the degree of association.

Comment: Also, spineplot in the coin package is useful for visualization.